# JSON .NET Object Mapping

Tags: c#, json, jenkins

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object I get from Jenkins server using JSON .NET. I would like to map the value highlighted in yellow to my Node.NodeType string property in C#.

[Property to be mapped to Node.NodeType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SutB8.png)

So I have the following JenkinsNodeContractResolver successfully mapping other properties but not just the deeper level of the property. Can someone please help me with this issue?

```
public class JenkinsNodesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> PropertyMappings { get; set; }

    public JenkinsNodesContractResolver()
    {
        PropertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"DisplayName", "displayName"},
            {"Icon", "icon"},
            {"ManualLaunchAllowed", "manualLaunchAllowed"},
            {"NumExecutors", "numExecutors"},
            {"Idle", "idle"},
            {"Offline", "offline"},
            {"OfflineCauseReason", "offlineCauseReason"},
            {"TemporarilyOffline", "temporarilyOffline"},
            {"NodeType", "hudson.node_monitors.ArchitectureMonitor"}
        };
    }

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        string resolvedName;
        var resolved = PropertyMappings.TryGetValue(propertyName, out resolvedName);
        return (resolved) ? resolvedName : base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried Newtonsoft.Json serializer / deserializer ?

Comment: Yes, I am using it. JenkinsNodesContractResolver is inherits from DefaultContractResolver which is a part of JSON .NET.